# Mod_Rewrite not rewriting URLs

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following url structure:

- /page.php?file=about
- /page.php?file=contact
- etc

.htaccess file has the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /page.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Does not try to rewrite the URLs at all. I'm looking for something like /about.html, /contact.html

Is it the .htaccess code or some kind of settings on the server?

Comment: Just some extra information, I've had Wordpress installed on the same server before and that rewrites URLs fine, so I'm pretty sure it's something I'm doing wrong!

Comment: What is the URL you're entering in browser? Is WP still being used?

Comment: Wordpress is off now, this is just a tiny site that I've made and tried to use a mega basic template system. URL I'm entering is site.com/page.php?file=about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?file=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ page.php?file=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: That rewrites the URL but actually tries to look for about.html for example, then obviously 404's because there's no file like that.

Comment: Something must still be wrong because it's not working like that

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure what information was required. If I remove .htaccess - site renders page template (page.php) with about page content, as intended. I'm just trying to get that URL to look more like /about.html as opposed to page.php?file=about

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /about.html was not found on this server.

Comment: Seems better as when I visit /about.html the URL rewrites to this: `/page.php?file=public_html/contact` but still not quite right

Comment: No idea, it's only appeared since trying that rule. Exact URL I've entered is: domain.com/about.html

Comment: It was in the root of the site, moving it to the same dir as public_html has fixed that. 

However - I think I have misunderstood how it rewrites. When I visit /about.html it redirects to page.php?file=about (which is what I wanted) - is there any way to keep /about.html in the address bar? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Your setup is not correct. `public_html` dir should have been website root but here is a subdirectory. I believe `page.php` is also in `public_html` right? If you control Apache then better make `public_html` your `DocumentRoot`